# Xorg release version in CentOS 5.4

Tags: centos, xorg

I want to know Xorg release version coming with CentOS 5.4, 
eg: Ubuntu 9.1 comes with XOrg 11 release 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 7.1 to me.

```
[rjune@couatl Public]$ rpm -q xorg-x11-apps
xorg-x11-apps-7.1-4.0.1.el5
```

Comment: hey thanks richard. now i feel ok to buy an ATI card :D